# Optimal Jtable size java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, pixel, text-size

I have written a program that reads a csv file and put it into a `jTable` that will be displayed in a seperate `jFrame` as a preview. Everything works fine but I would like to use the optimal size for the `jTable` in the preview frame.

So how to do it? Because if for example I choose another font for the text, the column would be wider or smaller? Is there a method to get the text-length in pixels (size)?`

The class looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/Gqz10pci

Thanks

Comment: Look at [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *"optimal size"*? Do you mean actual code, like a `Component`'s `.setPreferredSize()` method? Or you mean it as *"to use the available screen-space more appropriately"* (which is usually subjective)?

Comment: Consider `JDialog` rather than [multiple frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JTable` implements `Scrollable`, and the `preferredViewportSize` is arbitrarily set to `Dimension(450, 400)`. That size is obtained by wrapping the table in a `JScrollPane` and invoking `pack()` on the enclosing `Window`. Mindful of some important [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), you can use `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` to change the default size. A multiple of `getRowHeight()` may be a suitable choice for the height.